# Minimum Number of Clients (Sockets)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client-server

Please, I need some help!

I'm currently working on client-server program (sockets, Python).
I decided to build it like in this guide (https://codesource.io/creating-python-socket-server-with-multiple-clients/).
Each client has its own thread and connections are accepting in an infinitive loop. Sockets are using TCP.

According to the task server should support connection with at least 50 clients simultaneously.
How can I ensure it?
I can't find anything related to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python does not impose limits on the number of threads or socket file descriptors. The operating system (usually) has limits for both, e.g. 1024 file descriptors per process. Whatever those limits are, 50 is almost certainly within range. If you specify the operating system, we could look up the limits

Comment: Of course, my fault! It's Windows OS

Comment: I don't have an authoritative source at hand but according to these semi-official articles, you are orders of magnitude below the limits. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/ba-p/723848 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads You could also simply test it by starting 50 client processes, right?

Comment: Don't put anything that stops it from having more than 50. If you do it right it should just work. If you want to test it, you can simply connect to it 50 times at the same time, and see whether it works.